# compute all possible paired comparison for effect size in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to compare the means of different group with effect sizes (with cohends_d) for a list of factor.

I'd like to compute all the possible comparison (e.g. for cyl in mtcars 4 vs. 6, 6 vs. 8, 4 vs. 8).

Compare the mean of the mmpg for 4 cyl vs. 6 cyl etc. with cohens_d
For example this piece of code provides what I need :
`cohens_d(mpg ~ am, data = mtcars)`
but this one doesn't `cohens_d(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)` because I have too many level. I would not want to run all the paired comparison alone.

I would like to have at the end a dataframe with all the result of the paired comparison.

Here is the best code I have done yet.

The output are imcomplete, not well formated, the comparison are not very clear and  I guess incomplete.

Any suggestions for a code or package?

```
  library(effectsize) 
  mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(cyl, mpg) %>% 
  group_by(as.character(cyl)) %>%
  do(tidy(cohens_d(.$mpg))
```

Comment: You are looking for every possible combination of values for a single vector here?

Comment: Thanks a lot I was not clear enough in my answer. I have edited my question

Comment: 1. Please include all the necessary libraries to run the code. 2. Assuming `cohens_d` is from `rstatix` running your code gives an error `Error in get_formula_left_hand_side(formula) : argument "formula" is missing, with no default`. 3. If `cohens_d` is from `rstatix` package it requires a formula, only `.$mpg` is not enough. 4. How do you run this for one combination hardcoded manually? 5. What is the output that you want?

Comment: Thanks for your answer I have change my question considering your comments

Answer (score 1):

I believe the function that you are looking for to construct the list of things to compare is the crossing function.

I have demonstrated its usage below. I am happy to expand on this answer to include the data you were hoping to compare if you can clarify the comparison to be made.

```r
library(tidyverse)

crossing(cyl1 = mtcars$cyl, cyl2 = mtcars$cyl)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>    cyl1  cyl2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4     4
#> 2     4     6
#> 3     4     8
#> 4     6     4
#> 5     6     6
#> 6     6     8
#> 7     8     4
#> 8     8     6
#> 9     8     8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Also, can be in a pipe with `mtcars %>% distinct(cyl) %>% rerun(2, .) %>% reduce(crossing, .name_repair = 'unique')`

Comment: Interesting! I hadn'tconsidered this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution with the esvis package.

```
library(esvis)
```

`coh_d(mtcars, mpg ~ cyl)`